# My laptop's charger will not often work

Tags: laptop, battery, charging

I don't really know how to explain this problem or what causes it. My laptop charger takes a lot of work for it to actually charge my laptop. For example, I can't just plug it in. I have to move my laptop around, move the cable around, turn my laptop, etc. I have to repeat this process until that one time when it actually starts charging and I can let it sit there until it's finished. I have owned this charger for a pretty long time, so I think it might be old use. Also, when I pull out the charger out a little, the bar on the bottom will automatically light up white and then go back to showing nothing. When I do this, my laptop gets just enough charge to not discharge or discharge very slowly, but it won't actually charge any.

Comment: You have a broken cable or a broken port. Take it to a repair shop for proper testing.

Comment: Quick analysis: Worn connector(s) or a yanked cable. I'd say the cable is suspect. Probably folded way too many times. A SINGLE yank may cause that behavior.

Comment: Hmm... took about a minute to type that ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Your cable is probably faulty. Cables can become worn out and break over time from being yanked and folded too much.

Normally, laptop charges have two different plugs and a power supply. If you have a spare wire for either part I would try replacing it first. If you don't have one then Amazon or Ebay are probably your best bet for getting a new charger altogether.